# Paginate grouped query results with limit per page

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table of items:
`[id, name, category_id]`

And query expression: `name LIKE '%Smi%'`

A per_page limit is `100`.

Query results should be grouped by categories, and each page can display one or more categories with items.

Each page contains one or more category groups (with items), but total count of all items within all categories on the single page can not be greater then `per_page` (100), but at least one category.

Categories may not be broken down between multiple pages.

Items without categories ids (`null`), should be displayed as well in the middle of groups.

Conclusion: How to chunk in a groups, limits by group's total items counts?

Comment: what if one category has > 100 items? How can this be shown?

Comment: yes, it should be single category on a page

Comment: But it would have more than 100 items if it cannot be broken...

Comment: Which postgres version do you use?

Comment: its chunk will contain a single category group  inside. what a problem? the per_page is a 'desired' limit.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5.14

Comment: You have 2 constaints: 1. max row count = 100 2. categories can not be broken. So what if a category contains more than 100 items? One of both constraints would be failed. I want to know how to handle this case

Comment: categories should be arranged together in a chunks; if there are free space in a chunk (even if 1 free slot), next category should be placed in that chunk as well

Comment: is it an impossible task??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found no solution for one single query because there are certain dependencies between the rows which result in recursive issues. This could be really cruel. For example (for max rows per group == 5):

```
CATEGORY_ID | NUMBER OF ROWS
------------+----------------
      1     |   4
      2     |   3
      3     |   2
      4     |   1
```

If I would simply add the columns I would get 4 for the first line. It's its own page. The next will be 7 rows (4 + 3). 7 is bigger than 5, new page. Now I would have 9 (4 + 3 + 2). Same category as before. And next I would get 10. Normally the next page would be generated at 11. So the 4th category will be taken into the same page as 2 and 3 (which would not fit of course because that are 6 rows). The reason is that the simple SUM does not count the one empty row of the first page (where only 4 rows were taken). So in theory we need to store the difference between the next step of 5 and the actually filled rows. That has to be added for the next rows and so one. So every SUM of every single row recursively depends on the difference of the previous rows. That's really hard to do within a simple query.

---

**My solution** comes up with a simple imperative function:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0d5d26eecd638e6f8d60d82f3d621022)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_category_for_page(_max_rows int, _page_id int, _filter text) RETURNS int[] AS $$
DECLARE
    _remainder int := _max_rows;
    _page_counter int := 1;
    _categories int[] = '{}';
    _temprow record;
BEGIN
    FOR _temprow IN

        SELECT                                                    -- 1
            category_id, count(*)
        FROM categories 
        WHERE name LIKE _filter
        GROUP BY category_id
        ORDER BY category_id

    LOOP
        IF (_remainder - _temprow.count < 0) THEN                 -- 2
            _page_counter := _page_counter + 1;
            _remainder := _max_rows;
        END IF;

        IF (_page_counter > _page_id) THEN                        -- 3
            EXIT;
        END IF;

        _remainder := _remainder - _temprow.count;                -- 4

        IF (_page_counter = _page_id) THEN                        -- 5
            _categories := _categories || _temprow.category_id;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _categories;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function takes 3 parameters:

1. the maximum rows per page
2. the index of the page you are interested in
3. the `name` filter text

**Explanation**:

1. This query calculates the amount of rows per category. The result is going to be iterated within the `LOOP`:
2. The `_remainder` stores the value of how many rows already fit into the current page. If the current category has more rows than the remainder allows a new page is generated (`_page_counter` increased) and the remainder will be reset.
3. If the `_page_counter` is higher than the interesting `_page_id` no further calculations are needed
4. The remainder will be decreased by the number of rows of the current category
5. If the `_page_counter` equals the interesting `_page_id` the current category will be added to the output. This can happen several times.

Now you can call the function this way:

```
SELECT get_category_for_page(5, 1, '%A%');
```

So finally your query will look like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM categories
WHERE 
    category_id = ANY(get_category_for_page(5, 1, '%A%')) 
    AND name LIKE '%A%'
ORDER BY id
```

---

**Disclaimer**:

Think about a `_max_rows == 5`. Now your first category has 6 rows. Because this category will exceed the max row per page it has to be split to fit into one page. But your constraint says that a category mustn't be split. So there's no defined behavior to handle this special case. So this function only works if the number of rows of every single category is less or equal `_max_rows`.